# Eclipse - Default Workspaces for Each Perspective

Tags: eclipse, default, workspace, perspective

I was just wondering if there is a way for me to easily click a perspective and have it change to a default workspace.  I currently have two workspaces:  1 for PyDev (Python) and 1 for Java.  I also have two perspectives: PyDev and Java.  Is there a way for the PyDev workspace to be put into action when I click the Python perspective (and for the Java workspace to be started once I click the Java perspective)?

I'm quite new to this, but it would be helpful so I don't have to keep switching back and forth through the file settings.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to consider having one workspace with multiple projects (Java and Python) and then just switch the perspectives depending on what are working on.  You could alternatively launch multiple instances of Eclipse, one for each workspace if you need to keep them separate.  To directly answer your question, I don't believe what you are asking for is easily possible without potentially a special plug-in.

Comment: In addition to @deraj's advice, I recommend using Working Sets to manage what's visible. Search the Eclipse Help Contents for details on using Working Sets.

Comment: @deraj is correct, switching perspectives happens *within* one workspace.  You can switch workspaces and have different perspectives open in each.